# How to install neo4django in virtual environment

Tags: django, neo4j, neo4django

I receive the error below when trying to install neo4django in my virtual environment. Not sure what the problem is. The server is running on my machine and py2neo works with the restful api, but not neo4django.

I'm running ubuntu 12.0.4 with the latest version of neo4j installed (1.9-M01) and jdk 1.7 (openjkd) installed with JAVA_HOME pointing to: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 443, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 382, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 196, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 232, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/neowiki/nodes/management/commands/testcmd.py",
>   line 10, in handle
>       pete = Person.objects.create(name='Pete')   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/db/models/manager.py",
>   line 41, in create
>       return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 747, in create
>       return super(NodeQuerySet, self).create(**kwargs)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 377, in create
>       obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 325, in save
>       return super(NodeModel, self).save(using=using, **kwargs)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 463, in save
>       self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)   File
>   "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 340, in save_base
>       self._save_neo4j_node(using)   File "", line 2, in _save_neo4j_node   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 115, in trans_method
>       ret = func(*args, **kw)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 370, in _save_neo4j_node
>       typesToIndex=type_names_to_index)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/neo4jclient.py",
>   line 179, in gremlin_tx
>       return self.gremlin(script, tx=True, **params)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/neo4jclient.py",
>   line 168, in gremlin
>       params)   File "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/neo4jclient.py",
>   line 153, in send_script
>       script_rv = ext.execute_script(s, params=params, **execute_kwargs)   File
>   "/home/alan/workspace/neowiki/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4jrestclient/client.py",
>   line 1960, in **call**
>       raise StatusException(response.status, msg) neo4jrestclient.request.StatusException: Error [400]: Bad Request. Bad
>   request syntax or unsupported method. Invalid data sent:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script4.groovy: 94: unable to resolve class
>   org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.CypherParser  @ line 94, column 1.
>   import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.CypherParser    ^
>
> 1 error

My requirements.txt includes:

-e git://github.com/scholrly/neo4django.git@eefdf6a122fdbe26c62b6563f9ff6b30a4de2f93#egg=neo4django-dev

neo4jrestclient==1.7.0

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, your installation is fine. The problem is the version of Neo4j.

So far, we only support Neo4j 1.6-1.8. While I try to support all major releases in use, I typically extend support for milestones closer to a general release. For example, I didn't extend support to Neo4j 1.8 until it hit milestone 6.

Is there a particular reason you're using 1.9M01, or would the most recent stable release (1.8GA) suffice?

Comment: Just wondering--what do you need to do to support 1.9M01? It looks like it's coughing on some Groovy Cypher dependency--are you sure this is your piece causing that?

Comment: I'm not sure what it would take (not much, I hope?) to support 1.9M01, but you never know until you try. Most upgrades are easy, but I try to maintain backwards compatibility as far as the Neo4j downloads page, which can be a pain. I'm familiar with that particular bit of code referenced in the traceback. Neo4django comes with a Groovy/Gremlin lib that uses the CypherParser class. After a quick Google, it looks like the class was deprecated, and possibly removed in 1.9.

Comment: I'm new to neo4j and just took the latest snapshot- I'll give it a try with 1.8. Thanks for your quick reply!